# Any reason to use Spring @Async on external calls

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, asynchronous

When @Async is applied to a method making an external call, that Tomcat request thread is now able to handle the next incoming request. But what happens when the external service returns?

If the same thread pool is used, theoretically when the external service returns, all the threads **could** be busy and now we have to wait for a free thread - which means using @Async can actually be slower in this case.

I'm asking just to see the benefits of @Async and to confirm my understanding.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In itself calling an `@Async` method doesn't free up a Tomcat thread - you need to combine it with e.g. `DeferredResult<>` or `AsyncContext`/`startAsync()` - then the asynchronous method will run on a thread from a separate pool (configurable via Spring), and as you say the original thread can be freed to process another request.

If your Tomcat thread pool is processing other, shorter-lived types of request as well, this allows many of these requests to be processed while waiting for your slow external request to complete, so obviously that's an immediate benefit. If your other requests are frequent enough and/or intensive enough that they're maxing out your Tomcat thread pool, you're going to have performance issues anyway, async threads or not.

If on the other hand your Tomcat request threads are always just firing off these external calls asynchronously, it would be very unlikely that your Tomcat pool would be exhausted before you hit other limits. The advantage in this case is that you can have more requests in parallel than threads in your Tomcat thread pool.

All of the above assumes you are using `DeferredResult<>`, `AsyncContext/startAsync()` etc. to free up the Tomcat thread, but even if you're not doing that there are still cases where `@Async` can be useful, e.g.

- You want to make multiple external requests which can run in parallel and which may take significant time to execute - see the GitHub API example in the [Spring guides](https://spring.io/guides/gs/async-method/)
- You have some significant processing to do locally and your external request can execute in parallel to that. In that case you fire off the `@Async` request, then do your local work, then wait for the request to finish.

Comment: I thought @Async causes the called method to occur asynchronously, which means the caller returns immediately, no? How come that doesn’t free up a Tomcat thread?

Comment: the *caller* doesn't return immediately, the call to the `@Async` method returns a `Future<>` object immediately *to the caller*. The caller (your code) then continues to execute in parallel, on the original Tomcat thread. So you still need to separately free up that thread, if that's what you want to do. But you can also do other stuff (work, or other async calls) and then wait for the async to finish. See the FB example I linked to - the main thread runs a sleep loop waiting for the async calls. The main thread is equivalent to your tomcat thread. Make sense?

Comment: oops, I meant GitHub API example :)

Comment: As an aside, calling a method couldn't make your code suddenly return immediately. Obviously it could throw an exception, but otherwise your code is going to keep right on executing from the next statement. The `@Async` annotation tells spring to insert a proxy that runs the method on another thread so it may seem a bit like "magic", but it still can't break the basic laws of java

Comment: Thanks for clarifying - it all makes sense. Just want to be clear, your 2nd and 3rd paragraph in the response is assuming using @Async with DeferredResult Or AsyncContext, correct?

Comment: Correct - I've clarified that slightly in the text now, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand, an `@Async` method will be run in a new thread. That new thread will remain occupied until the external service returns. So, if your pool lacks threads, it will impact when the method is called, and the request will hang until a free thread is found.

All this can be verified by logging  `Thread.currentThread().getName()`.

Yes, if there will be lack of free threads, there would be no benefit of `@Async`. A solution would be to increase the number of threads in the pool.